# Make dropzone.js aware of changes in DOM

Tags: dropzone.js

I have some forms with the class `dropzone` added dynamically to the DOM after page load. How can I make dropzone.js aware of these addition in order to make sure they can be dropped upon instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out that it's as simple as:

`$(".newly-added-form").dropzone();`